# How to differentiate the request from.net Web browser control or normal browser?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have requirement to stop request coming from .net browser control to server. I have created http module and plug into asp.net website. Code is like below:

```
public class CustomAuthentication : IHttpModule
{
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(this.OnPreRequestHandlerExecute);
    }

    public void OnPreRequestHandlerExecute(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication) source;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;

        logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, context.Request.UserAgent);
        if (context.Request.Browser.Browser.Contains("IE")
        {
            context.Response.Status = "403 Forbidden";
            context.Response.Close();
        }
```

Normal IE browser is also sending same name. I am not able to restrict request only for .Net IE browser because, normal IE browser is also sending same name. Is there any attribute which can be used to identify if request is coming from .net browser?

Comment: I can't think of a sane way to implement this - but there again, I can't imagine a *sane* reason to want to achieve this anyway. Why should the User Agent be, in any way, a consideration on whether to provide access? Also, bear in mind that *everything* that comes from the browser is inherently untrustworthy - so even if there was an "attribute" it would almost certainly be controllable and fakable from the client side.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to know if request is comming from .NET browser control or normal IE.

If you can change this program that is using web browser control, then you can put custom user agent and then block such request. Here is the explanation how to change user agend of .NET browser control:

http://www.lukepaynesoftware.com/articles/programming-tutorials/changing-the-user-agent-in-a-web-browser-control/